# Sentinel 3 data changes in Google Earth Engine platform since 2021

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, sentinel, sentinel-3

For calculating Cl-a in lake waters, I'm using three bands of Sentinel-3; one of them is band 10 (Oa10_radiance). Since 2021, the values of this band and band #1 contain nonsense, very low negative values instead of valid data. Maybe someone already resolved this problem?[image]